# iOS CoreMotion DeviceMotion Gravity Angles

Tags: ios, core-motion, devicemotion

I noticed the values returned by the gravity.z component seem to follow a cosine curve:

- gravity.z = 0      = cos(90) (iPhone in portrait mode)
- gravity.z = -.707  = cos(45) (iPhone tilted back by 45 degrees)
- gravity.z = -1     = cos(0)  (iPhone laying flat, face side up)

Am I correct in that the values are just a cosine? The .x and .y values also seem to follow a cosine curve.

```
if manager.deviceMotionAvailable {
    manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01
    manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), withHandler: { (data, error) -> Void in

        // data.gravity.x
        // data.gravity.y
        // data.gravity.z
    })
}
```

Comment: There may be more info if you look into the [spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) (r, theta, rho) and how it converts to Cartesian coordinates (x, y, z). In this case I think `r = 1`.

Comment: Those are the correct formulas. Thank you!